# How to get the unique value by comparing the first column from a list of three csv files?

Tags: python

There are two files in each file.

import csv

counts = {}

for a in sys.argv[2:]:

```
with open(a) as c:

    # Read it as a CSV file.

    reader = csv.reader(c, delimiter=' ')

        count = counts.get(row[0], 0)

        counts[row[0]] = count + 2
```

print([i for i, c in counts.items() if c == 2])

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not here to write programs for you, or solve homeworks

Comment: @ltps 'in file3 their is no unique because 11 and 77 are repeated' NOT TRUE

Answer (score 0):

You should really try for yourself. But assuming that you want to find the numbers that are unique over *all* files, this works.

```
import csv
import sys

# Count all first-column numbers.
counts = {}

# Loop over all input files.
for a in sys.argv[1:]:

    # Open the file for reading.
    with open(a) as c:
        # Read it as a CSV file.
        reader = csv.reader(c, delimiter=' ')
        for row in reader:
            # Get the current count of the number in the first column.
            # Default is 0.
            count = counts.get(row[0], 0)
            # Increment the count by 1.
            counts[row[0]] = count + 1

# Print only those numbers that have a count of 1.
print([i for i, c in counts.items() if c == 1])
```

Use it like

```
$ python3.5 so.py file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv
```

Output:

```
['22', '55']
```